# Inserting QSvgWidget in QTableWidget cell

Tags: python, svg, pyqt4, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

What I want to do is to load .svg file and show (render) it in qtableWidget cell.
First part I've done like this:

```
svgWidget = QSvgWidget("C:\mySVG.svg")
svgWidget.setMaximumSize(100,100)
```

next line renders svg like what I expected:

```
widget.show()
```

but when I've tried this:

```
self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(svgWidget))
self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, svgWidget)
```

neither of those lines inserts svgWidget in tableWidget cell.
How should I do that? Examples would be appreciated, I'm still a noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
self.ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i, j, svgWidget)
```

Comment: That's it, thank you. I have one more problem now: in other columns I have some text and `self.ui.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()` stretches height of svgWidget . Is there a way to add white space in cell so `resizeRowsToContents()` do not affect svgWidget, or  to lock aspect ratio of svgWidget? I've googled and tried second one, but unsuccessfully(nothing happened):
`qsp = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred,QSizePolicy.Preferred)
qsp.setHeightForWidth(True)    
svgWidget.setSizePolicy(qsp)`